# Why is there no shadows after rendering in Eevee?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, shadows

I'm relative new to blender, I'm trying to do a turntable for a product and using EEVEE for fast renders, the problem is, there is no shadows after rendering, everything looks ok on the viewport and i think i have all the things that should be on on, or maybe I'm missing something. Any help would be very much appreciated.

I'm talking about the background shadows on the floor and the above logo shadows.

Render view from viewport
[image]

EEVEE Render
[image: Eevee Render]

[Blend file link](https://mega.nz/file/3zgRwCqa#89GiTo0z1vmJKxpTh35LDfR5ywV__uyogfYKgM1HXt0)

Comment: They look the same to me.

Comment: pls provide blend file and show us which shadow you are missing (maybe with arrows)...do you mean the shadow in the background?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you disabled this plane [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdIrG.png but not in render. This prevents the plane behind it and so you see now shadow. Just disable that too by clicking on the camera icon. result: [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cryJE.jpg

Comment: Thank you very much, i lost a couple of hour on this and it was so simple :) Thank you again